# substring two changing words in an xsl variable

Tags: xslt, substring

I want to create two variables out of one variable containing two words in XSL.

The variable $string could come in as follows:

"red car"

"red bike"

"blue car"

...

The goal is to end up with two variables:

$color: red, blue, etc.

$vehicle: car, bike, etc.

Comment: Which version of XSLT/XPath do you use? And please show the exact XSLT definition of that first variable as it is not clear whether you have a sequence of three strings or a single string concatenating those three values (without having shown clearly how they are concatenated).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bind one variable to `substring-before($string, ' ')` and the other to `substring-after($string, ' ')`